# Convert PHP query to MS Access

Tags: ms-access

How do I convert this query to MS Access?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id='11101958' OR number LIKE '%t11101958%' OR name LIKE '%t11101958%') OR (dateofbirth='1958-10-11' AND SUBSTR(name,1,1)='t') ORDER BY name LIMIT 0,10;
```

I have already found out:

`LIMIT 0,10` > `TOP 10`

`dateofbirth='1958-10-11' AND SUBSTR(name,1,1)='t'` > `dateofbirth=#10-11-1958# AND LEFT(name,1)='t'`

What I can't seem to find out is how to have 2 sets of "AND". So basically I have:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table WHERE (id='11101958' OR number LIKE '%t11101958%' OR name LIKE '%t11101958%') OR (dateofbirth=#10-11-1958# AND SUBSTR(name,1,1)='t') ORDER BY name;
```

Also: is it correct that I have to search for mm-dd-yyyy instead of dd-mm-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: What do you mean by "Two sets of "AND"" There is only one AND in your original mysql query. I think you just need to change out `Substr(name, 1, 1) = 't'` to `LEFT(name, 1) = "t"` and then go back and change all of your single quotes to double for your string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of the wild char `%` in Access is `*`.
The equivalent of `SUBSTR()` is `MID()` but since you want only the 1st char then `LEFT()` works too.
Instead of `LIMIT` use `TOP`.
You can use the format `yyyy-mm-dd` for the dates:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM table 
WHERE (id='11101958' OR number LIKE '*t11101958*' OR name LIKE '*t11101958*') 
   OR (dateofbirth=#1958-10-11# AND LEFT(name,1)='t') 
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost works. When I add a string instead of an integer for "id" the query fails.

Comment: If the data type of the id is integer you should pass an integer or instead of `id = '5'` pass `id = val('5')`

Comment: BTW: TOP 10 doesn't seem to work. It simply shows the complete result set...

Comment: TOP 10 is the way to set the LIMIT in Access.

Comment: Check this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-24f2a47d-a803-4c7c-8e81-756fe298ce57